# Audio User Space Plug-In Driver

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, sandbox, hal

I have a code signed HAL plugin driver. What is the appropriate way to check authenticity of my driver to ensure nothing in my resource folder has been modified?

I'm currently trying the **SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath** approach from Security framework that I use on my other projects. [similar to this link](https://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/checking-code-signing-and-sandboxing-status-in-code/)

However, I'm getting tons of error messages in my console:

kernel[0]: Sandbox: coreaudiod(64363) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Library/Audio

and **SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath** function would return

`errSecCSStaticCodeNotFound =       -67068, /* cannot find code object on disk */`

It seems like a sandboxing restriction to me. I've also tried the entitlement

> com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only
>   `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/`

with no luck.

I simply want to verify the code signing information within my codes.

Any suggestion would be nice. 
Thanks.